# How to calculate "Daily user engagement" on Big Query and get the same result that Firebase shows in its dashboard?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to calculate the amount of time the average user spent in my app on a particular day.

I just read [this great post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html) from Todd Kerpelman on Firebase Blog that explains how to do it. With a little modification on his query I reached the solution bellow:

```html
SELECT AVG(user_daily_engagement_time/1000/60)
FROM(
SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_date, sum(engagement_time) AS user_daily_engagement_time
FROM (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_date,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 
      "engagement_time_msec") AS engagement_time
  FROM `mydataset.events_20201104`
)
WHERE engagement_time > 0 
GROUP BY 1,2)
```

The problem is that when I compare it with Firebase analytics (for the same period) it gives me a difference higher than 2 minutes. In this case the BigQuery answer is >2minutes higher than the Firebase Dashboard.

Comment: The fix is available for instances with [Firebase Android SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#analytics_v17-2-2) version greater than 17.2.2. Could you please share your SDK version?

Comment: Thank you @Ines actually we're using [@react-native-firebase/analytics”: “7.6.1"](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) which references to Firebase BoM 25.7.0 / Analytics 17.4.4